# Subset sum standard dp for -ve numbers using 1-d array?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a large array of +ve and -ve numbers.I cannot use 2-dimensional array. I want to find total number of subsets whose sum is equal to K. There is a standard algorithm which i am not aware of.Size of array is larger than 100000. Can you please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a DP approach using a 2D array, you could easily change it to not use a 2D array, but I assume that that won't help you solve your problem, as this would result in the same running time. Can you tell us why you can't (or think you can't) use a 2D array?

Comment: It will take 100000*100000 space.

Comment: You can use binary tree instead

Comment: @NarendraYadav do u actually need to store the entire 2D array or only 1 previous row will work.